# f:convertDateTime returns wrong date and time

Tags: oracle, hibernate, date, datetime

I have a DB table with field from type DATE and i would like to show it on the user interface in this format 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss'. I get it using Hibernate query and convert it using:

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss" />
```

But the result is not what i expected.

for example:

```
8.6.2014 03:00:00 (from the DB)  -> 08.00.2014 12:00:00 (in the user interface)
15.6.2014 12:00:00 (from the DB) -> 15.00.2014 12:00:00 (in the user interface)
```

I added in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

My timeZone is UTC+02:00

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Month is represented with capital "M". In your case, it would be:

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
```

**EDIT**

You should add your timeZone too:

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" timeZone="GMT+2" />
```

**EDIT 2**

If it doesn't work, you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://java67.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/how-to-format-date-in-java-simpledateformat-example.html):

```
public static String dateToString(Date date, String format) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

And then:

```
String newDate = dateToString(myDate, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Not it shows: 8.6.2014 03:00:00 (from the DB) -> 08.06.2014 12:00:00 (always 12:00:00 o'clock)

Comment: Now shows 09:00:00 for all without changing nothing.

Comment: What pattern did you try?

Comment: Yours - <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss" />

Comment: Try `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss` instead

Comment: It is worse - 8.6.2014 03:00:00 is shown like 07.06.2014 21:00:00

Comment: I've added more info to my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for you willing to help me :) This does not work properly too. It shows for all records 23:00:00 o'clock. May be the problem comes from field data type... Do you think that i should change the data type of the field in JAVA class  (now java.Util.Date) and in the Oracle DB (now DATE) with something else (and if yes with what)?

Comment: I've never worked with JSF so I can't imagine why you are getting a wrong hour, but you could use [SimpleDateFormat](http://java67.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/how-to-format-date-in-java-simpledateformat-example.html) instead, and get the correct date in your bean.

Answer (score 0):

try this
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm:ss" type="both" timeZone="UTC+02"/>